# Wireless adapter keeps losing connection in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, wireless-adapter

I have a RNX-N150UBE wireless adapter that keeps losing connection on my Desktop machine whenever I boot into windows 7. The wireless adapter works fine when I boot into my Linux Ubuntu system. Therefore, I believe it is a windows problem.

By the way, this problem started when I was playing Dota 2 (it is a Steam game).

my System specs:

[image]

What I have tried so far:

1. uninstall and reinstall the wireless adapter drivers.
2. tried using the windows drivers only.
3. Tried using other USB ports.
4. Updated my router's firm Ware and changed the channel.

NOTE: I did notice other wireless routers in my neighbourhood that keep disappearing and reappearing in the Wireless Connection Window. Also, in my Network Connections I have this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer but it is a bit odd.

The channel I had was set to 9 in my router at home and I noticed that other three routers in my neighborhood had the same channel. Thus, I changed my channel to 11 yesterday and later today the other three routers in my neighborhood somehow have the same channel as I do! I decided to change my password and switch my router's channel to some other number. I was able to get fast internet again and I am able to play games online. I will wait and see if this happens again. I might change the network security encryption type if it does.

Comment: The spectrum is very crowded.  Also, for 802.11b/g, there are only three channels that don't overlap... 1, 6, and 11.  (Outside of the US, you can use #14.)  Many routers change channels dynamically when there is congestion.

Comment: @Brad Thank you for this useful information! I'll be sure to remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest drivers from here (Softpedia link) http://drivers.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php/d6772d423bebd1733609d85f79cf90fc/5469056a/400b5/0/1

Install then try again.

If still no joy purchase another as they can be found for less than 10GBP online.